# How to change the default text in a dropdown menu when item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu and it has 'Action' as the default text.
When I click on one of the dropdown items I would like it to be set to the text in the text field, but it doesn't. How do I get it so that it sets the visible text after I select an item.

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Not Listed</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you include all the JS and CSS files required like jquery.js etc?? Try this out: http://jsbin.com/gafoci/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with jQuery. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this, but for each drop-down item, you could just create a function that changes the text of the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#item1').on('click', function() {
    $('#item0').text('Active');
  });

  $('#item2').on('click', function() {
    $('#item0').text('Not Listed');
  });

});
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/kYK0FAEDFz

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a traditional Select Dropdown? I believe this would accomplish your goals.

```
<select>
<option>Action</option>
<option>Not Listed</option>
</select>
```